# spyder launch error: self.curr_filenames.pop(index) pop index out of range

Tags: python, spyder

my spyder won't launch and shows the following err: (
I just uninstalled old anaconda from windows remove programs, and reinstalled `Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64.exe`.)

```
(base) C:\Users\XYZ>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 219, in main
    mainwindow.main()
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3763, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3638, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 984, in setup
    plugin = module.PLUGIN_CLASS(self)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\plugin.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.pylint = PylintWidget(self, max_entries=max_entries,
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\widgets\pylintgui.py", line 252, in __init__
    self.set_filename(f)
  File "C:\Users\XYZ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pylint\widgets\pylintgui.py", line 279, in set_filename
    self.curr_filenames.pop(index)
IndexError: pop index out of range
[13520:380:0727/173051.399:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
[19460:22120:0727/173051.400:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been stuck on this issue for the past 4 hours... Trying many uninstalls and installs, etc.

My fix was:

When in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
spyder --reset
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me 3 hrs and 55mins!